# Is there a MAC for Linux that can stop a process on policy violations?

Tags: linux, security, selinux, apparmor, grsecurity

Is there a Linux MAC that can `SIGSTOP` a process (or otherwise don't return the control from the syscall involved) on policy violations so I can resume it with an updated policy to retry the syscall? This would be very handy in case of running interactive untrusted software that takes a lot of time to change its state and exhibit new behaviour. Also could be used to dissect the running process state (with gdb, for instance) to locate bugs/malicious code that need to get fixed or reported.

Answer (score 1):

No - selinux will only block the action in the case of a policy violation.  If you really, really wanted this behavior, you could consume the selinux log, parse out PIDs, and send SIGSTOP to each.  However, the process would have already received the denial from selinux, so resuming the process would not retry the syscall.  Furthermore, if this sort of behavior was standard, it would open the server up to a number of DoS attacks (imagine what would happen if a client could trick `httpd` into performing a benign policy violation)

Answer (score 0):

[Tomoyo Linux](https://tomoyo.osdn.jp/1.8/chapter-13.html.en) can achieve that by executing a command (like `killall`) when a policy is violated.

You can as well use [`tomoyo-queryd`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/tomoyo-tools/tomoyo-loadpolicy.8.en.html) to monitor the policy violation in real-time (and decide to allow/deny in real-time)